# recording user selections and altering textview strings via java code

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, input

Im new to android programming (and java for that matter). Although i do have a good grasp on programming concepts.

what im trying to do as an exercise to help build my understanding is create a simple text adventure. i want to begin by offering the user the ability to select something like a player race or class (which will ultimately determine how the story plays out). i plan on doing so with radio buttons (or perhaps even a normal button).

my question is this. when the user selects their class (ie: "Mage") i want that choice to be stored. from there i want to be able to define a conditional statement that will alter which story the user will be given. the problem is that i do not yet have a grasp on the process for recording the users selection, and altering the text in a textview (or any other view)

once i know how to record which variable the user chose and test it in an "if" statement, then alter the output of a view from within this conditional, i will be on my way.

thanks in advance =)

Comment: PS: i have done quite a bit of research on the subject, but all the documentation was just that, documentation. it delves too quickly into new concepts before i understand the fundamentals of what im trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

First you would want to create a radio group in your layout XML file and then give each radio button an id value to reference from the java code like this:

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/RadGroup">
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/Rad1"
    android:text="Radio1"/>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/Rad2"
    android:text="Radio2"/>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/Rad3"
    android:text="Radio3"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Then from there you could use an if statement or a switch statement and as for altering a TextView you could use `myTextView.setText("myString")` and you could use that within each if to achieve different text values.

Comment: so how would i use the id to test this? would i have to use a findviewbyid or what? also, will this selection persist through to other activities?

Comment: You need to use findviwwby id. Assign whatever is in your view to a variable. There are several ways for passing data to other activities. You could use an intent for example